# MySQL server not starting. Server-side SQL bad statement? Corrupted table? Cpanel autoupdate?

Tags: mysql, centos, cpanel

Yesterday the mysql service stopped working from my dedicated server, taking down several webpages and other applications that run on it. Maybe a cpanel autoupdate didn't finished correctly but I've only recieved warnings emails with this error:

```
(XID ######) The “mysql” service is down.
```

and the first one says:

```
The subprocess “/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_mysql” reported error number 2 when it ended.
```

System and server info:

- OS: CentOS Linux 8.3
- Apache Version: 2.4.46
- MySQL Version:  Ver 8.0.25 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
- PHP Version: 7.4.18
- Cpanel v94.0.8

I'm going to list some commands I've tried and their output:

```
# systemctl start mysqld
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then:

```
# systemctl status mysqld.service
 ESCOD
 mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service.d
           └─limits.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-05-11 17:33:19 UTC; 53s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 27686 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 27657 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 27686 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Server upgrade complete"
    Error: 2 (No such file or directory)

May 11 17:33:17 xx-xx-xx-xx.cprapid.com mysqld[27686]: 2021-05-11T17:33:17.655235Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock>
May 11 17:33:17 xx-xx-xx-xx.cprapid.com mysqld[27686]: 2021-05-11T17:33:17.670697Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade frrom '80024' to '80025' started.>
May 11 17:33:18 xx-xx-xx-xx.cprapid.com mysqld[27686]: 2021-05-11T17:33:18.064279Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-010725] [Server] Couldn't repair table: mysql.general_log>
May 11 17:33:18 xx-xx-xx-xx.cprapid.com mysqld[27686]: 2021-05-11T17:33:18.064383Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement '-- Create general_log CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS general_log (event_time TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), user_host MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL, thread_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, server_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, command_type VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, argument MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL) engine=CSV CHARACTER SET utf8 comment="General log"; 'failed with error code = 1034, error message = 'Incorrect key file for table 'general_log'; try to repair it'.>>
May 11 17:33:18 xx-xx-xx-xx.cprapid.com mysqld[27686]: 2021-05-11T17:33:18.065026Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade >
May 11 17:33:18 xx-xx-xx-xx.cprapid.com mysqld[27686]: 2021-05-11T17:33:18.065176Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
May 11 17:33:18 xx-xx-xx-xx.cprapid.com mysqld[27686]: 2021-05-11T17:33:18.987996Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.>
May 11 17:33:19 xx-xx-xx-xx.cprapid.com systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 11 17:33:19 xx-xx-xx-xx.cprapid.com systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 11 17:33:19 xx-xx-xx-xx.cprapid.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
```

---

```
# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

This file doesn't exist but there's one located in `/tmp/mysql.sock`. Later, I changed some lines in my.cnf but got the same error

```
#mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

---

```
# nano /etc/my.cnf

[client]

socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
disable-log-bin=1
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
innodb_file_per_table=1
performance-schema=0
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

As said before, I changed `socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` to `socket=/tmp/mysql.sock` for both client and mysqld. No more changes done.

---

```
# mysqld -u root
2021-05-11T17:11:04.993623Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25) starting as process 25020
2021-05-11T17:11:04.997863Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-05-11T17:11:05.146263Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-05-11T17:11:05.432633Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-05-11T17:11:05.447752Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80024' to '80025' started.
2021-05-11T17:11:10.666062Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'ALTER TABLE user   MODIFY max_updates int unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,   MODIFY max_connections int unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,   MODIFY max_user_connections int unsigned DEFAULT 0  NOT NULL,   MODIFY ssl_cipher BLOB NOT NULL,   MODIFY x509_issuer BLOB NOT NULL,   MODIFY x509_subject BLOB NOT NULL; ' failed with error code = 1138, error message = 'Invalid use of NULL value'.
2021-05-11T17:11:10.666934Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.
2021-05-11T17:11:10.667061Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-05-11T17:11:12.059278Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Here I find interesting `'ALTER TABLE user   MODIFY...` It looks like to have an additional space (sorry if this is unimportant, I'm not an expert in this matter).

---

```
# ls -la /var/lib |grep mysql
drwxr-x--x  10 mysql          mysql          4096 May 12 00:24 mysql
drwxr-x---   2 mysql          mysql             6 Apr 23 16:18 mysql-files
drwxr-x---   2 mysql          mysql             6 Apr 23 16:18 mysql-keyring
```

Lastly, after detecting the incident, the server didn't respond to pings for an hour or so and needed to be unplug and restarted. Now I can access to the server through ssh but mysql still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you turned on the "general log", turn it off.

I did not spot anything obvious in changelog:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-25.html

<strike>Consider filing a bug at bugs.mysql.com</strike>

What "general*" files are in the `mysql` directory?  It *may* be possible to delete just those files.

**More**

> failed with error code = 13, error message

```
perror 13
OS error code  13:  Permission denied
```

Who is writing?  Who is running mysqld?  etc.

MySQL should be installed by `root` and `mysqld` should be run by a system process, not a user process.

Comment: Ok, "general log" turned off. What do you mean with _"general*"_ files? There are pem's, auto.cnf, mysql.ibd, etc and directories for the db's, mysql, performance_schema and sys inside the mysql directory.

Comment: @AsessionGuy - Possibly `general.csv`; maybe `general.frm`.

Comment: `general_log.csv` and `general_log.csm` are in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/`

Comment: Removing those two files may help it start.  (`mv` them to somewhere else, just in case this fix makes things worse.)

Comment: Well, it didn't work but the error changed to `Execution of server-side SQL statement '-- Create general_log CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS general_log (event_time TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), user_host MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL, thread_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, server_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, command_type VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, argument MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL) engine=CSV CHARACTER SET utf8 comment="General log"; ' failed with error code = 13, error message = 'Can't get stat of './mysql/general_log.CSV' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)'.`

Comment: I think I see the issue; see my additions.

Comment: Everything is written by root but I'm not sure if the process is owned by root, mysql or cpanel as I can't get it to work now. It was installed during cpanel installation.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone, I just encountered the same error message when there was nothing wrong with permissions.

The solution turned out to be SELinux preventing rename of the log file. If this is your issue, you will be able to see something like the following in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`:

```
avc:  denied  { rename } for  pid=2889079 comm="boot" name="general_log.CSV"
```